# RegEx capturing first (or only) group of 7 numbers max in a numeric/space string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

The exact rule is (translate from french, hope it will be correct) :

**6th rule** : In case the string is numeric (eventually with spaces) and the first or the only series of numbers is less or equal to 7 character, this serie is our "title n°"

- "1122584 44588985 1211" must return "1122584"
- " xx 122585 12585" must not match
- " 122585 1258xx5" must not match
- " 12224457887 5896" must return "5896"
- " 1458 125828 " must return "1458"

According to me "the first or only" is useless, if i find one i'm ok, no matter if it's the only one 'cause it's the first.
What i can't manage to do is both checking if the whole string is numeric/space AND finding my group matching.

I'll use the regex in Java 7, with this library : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

edit :

^[0-9\s]*$ is the regex to check numeric/space string

([0-9]{1,7}) is my captur group

I can't figure how to combine those two expressions.

Comment: You are being downvoted because you didn't post your current regex or code. Please post your efforts so far so we can help you better.

Comment: What have you tried? Post your regex so we can advise what needs fixing. We're not a homework doing service

Comment: sorry, i'm not used to post questions.

Answer (score 1):

([0-9]{1,7}) is your capture group, and you want to make sure all other characters are numeric/space.

So it becomes `^[0-9\s]*?\b([0-9]{1,7})\b[0-9\s]*$`